How do I exclude specific materials or vertices from Grease Pencil line art?
So I'm making a little animation with a cartoonish duck and added some line art with Grease Pencil. But here's the issue; it all looks good and nice, but there is line art around the duck's eyes because I enabled material borders, as the entire mesh, including facial features, needs to be one singular object. After all, I will use it in a physics cloth simulation (don't ask why ). The line art around the duck's eyes does not look good, as his eyes are already black, but as I mentioned earlier, I can't have them as separate meshes because of the physics simulation. I need the Material Borders option ticked because there are other materials that do need to be outlined, like the duck's beak.
If anybody needs the file, I would be glad to link it in a Google Drive.
Thanks in advance!
